# How to call a comma separator syntax from a string using string_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

Need help with figuring out how to call the second comma separator syntax (21 locations) from the following string example and by not calling "potential customers" or "hello world":

```
potential customers, 21 locations, hello world
```

Could I use:

```
select string_agg(tablename, '?')
```

I hope I am explaining this well. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Are there always only 2 comma ? I mean : seems you have a pattern like `foo, what you want, foo bis` but could it happen that `foo` (the first one) contained a comma, or even the `what you want` part ?

Comment: I have read your question twice and have no idea what you are asking. May be me, or the question is unclear. I can't even make sense of the title.

Comment: I think "call" means "extract" and "string_agg" should really be "string_part" or "regexp_split_to_array" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this :

```
SELECT split_part('foo foo, part I want, foo2 foo 2',', ',2);
```

You can see doc here : [PostgreSQL Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Function : `split_part(string text, delimiter text, field int)`

Return type : `text`

Description :

> Split string on delimiter and return the given field (counting from
>   one)